# How to divide separate parts the list created via ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering, angularjs-ng-repeat

I made list of countries that are shown via ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries.country | filter:search:startsWith">{{ country }}</li>
</ul>
```

Before that I've created an sorted array with all that countries:

```
var countriesNotSorted = ['Ukraine','Urugvai','Russia','Romania','Rome','Argentina','Britain','Indonesia','Germany','Brazil','Portugal','Polska','Uganda','Algeria','Andorra'],
    countriesArray = countriesNotSorted.sort();
```

Also I have list with clickable letters, when one of them is clicked list become sorted. Question is: is it possible in very beggining to divide the list of countries (that are shown via Angular ng-repeat) on separate parts, so `Algeria, Andorra, Argentina` and all  countires start on `'A'` will appear after some heading (e.g uppercase letter 'A')?

```
A:
Algeria
Argentina
Andorra

B:
Brazil
Bolgaria
Belgium
```

Here is my [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dxufUAcCifSUVEFJa0Ua?p=preview)

Thanx for your attention and time in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply `ng-repeat` over your alphabet array.

```
<div class="container">

    <input id="q" type="text" ng-model="search " />
    <div ng-repeat="letter in alphabet.letter" ng-show="countriesFiltered.length > 0">
      <h3>{{letter}}</h3>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="country in (countriesFiltered = (countries.country | filter:letter:startsWith | filter:search:startsWith))">{{ country }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4PcHfknP95xOI4KPIqVT?p=preview)